# How to scroll in a tableview programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 50 row in a tableview. How to show 10 row initially and on a button click next 10 and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` method in [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView)

Declare an index variable and when button pressed, increment that by 10, construct an `NSIndexPath` with that and call the above method.

Eg:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take 5 arrays and one main table array. In button click method You have to write

You should take an integer in .h as

.h

```
       int number;

      in viewDidLoad
  {

      number=0;
     tableArray=array1;
   }

        -(IBAction)btnClk:(id)sender
         {
          number++;
          if(number==5)
         {
          number=0;
         }
        if(number==0)
          {
        tableArray=array1;
        }
        if(number==1)
         {
      tableArray=array2;
        }
         if(number==2)
         {
     tableArray=array3;
          }
         if(number==3)
      {
    tableArray=array4;
     }
    if(number==4)
   {
     tableArray=array5;
   }

   [tableView reloadData];
```

}